# Unable to proxy Maven repo over https/ssl with Nexus

Tags: ssl, https, nexus, keytool, pkix

I followed the instructions given on [this page](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/sect-ssl-client-cert.html) to import the server certificate.

When I use `keytool -list`, I can see that the certificate is actually in the keystore. If I try to import the `.crt` file, `keytool` warns me that the keystore already contains the certificate.

Then I updated `wrapper.conf` with the two ssl options. I can see them on the command line of the Nexus process after a restart.

But when I try to add a proxy repo for the remote server, I always get `sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to import the custom CA certificate into the 'trustStore' and not into the 'keyStore'.

The procedure for creating a 'trustStore' is the same as the one for the 'keyStore'.
Once you have your *.jks file then link it using the following system properties:

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=<file>
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<password>
```

Answer (score 1):

Error message means the JVM cannot properly authenticate the remote server's SSL cert. Very common if the remote server is using a self-signed cert instead of one signed by an official certificate authority (like verisign).

Your message is confusing. You've enabled SSL on your Nexus instance, however you talk about a proxy repo implying the problem SSL cert might be on another server.

Comment: The proxy repo is on a https server and the HTTP client built into the Nexus server has trouble to connect. It's Maven -> Nexus -> Remote Server. The first connection works, the second is broken.

Comment: The remote server uses a self-signed certificate. I imported it into a keystore, specified the keystore on the command line and I'm sure the keystore is used (I tried with a wrong password). What else do I have to do to make Java use the certs in the keystore?