# Maven+Nexus+Jenkins SSL certificate error

Tags: maven, ssl, jenkins, ssl-certificate, nexus

I have installed certificate to nexus. When i start jenkins builder im getting an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project wf-base: Could not resolve dependencies for project 1.0.0o-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at 1.0.0o-SNAPSHOT: 

Failed to read artifact descriptor for 1.0.0o-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact 1.0.0o-SNAPSHOT from/to Nexus (https://nexus.repository.link): 

sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options for those of you (like me) who stumbled on this issue.

### 1. Import CA in java trust store

The first option is to import your *certificate authority(ies)* in your `jre` `cacert` file using `keytool`.

This option, although it seems to be the most natural, has one drawbacks: this implies to have write access to the JRE / JDK folders, which is not always the case.

### 2. Pass trust store as a param to the JVM in Maven using Jenkins

Here is the trick: `maven` passes a set of parameters to the `jvm` before it runs. These parameters are wrapped in a variable called `MAVEN_OPTS` wihch are initialized in the `mvn` script.

The way to go when using Jenkins is to create an environment variable in your slave or your job, call it `MAVEN_OPTS` and give it the `JVM` option:

```
MAVEN_OPTS
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=your_custom_cert_file
```

As always, there are many other possibilities but these two are the cleanest ones.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a certificate in the chain so your certificate isn't trusted,if it's a self signed certificate you'll need to add it as a root certificate. If the certificate was issued by a CA you'll need to download the missing certificate(s) in the chain and install them.

Comment: all of these components are behind proxy, is it important or not?

Comment: i have found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851153/unable-to-proxy-maven-repo-over-https-ssl-with-nexus

the right answer said that i need to add my certificate into truststore, not in keystore.

im gonna try this and remind you when it will be finished